# Scatterplot with Cartopy and Matplotlib produces cut-off map

Tags: matplotlib, scatter, cartopy

I am trying to do a scatterplot on a map with Robinson Projection. However, the produced [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeOY8.png) is cut off at the side and I cannot figure out why. I did not have any problems when doing contour plots on similar maps. The longitude and latitude for the points, I want to plot, are stored in two seperate lists with floats (lon, lat), like this:

lon = [2.906250000000000000e+02, 2.906250000000000000e+02, 2.906250000000000000e+02, ...]

lat = [-5.315959537001968016e+01, -5.129437713895114825e+01,-4.942915369712304852e+01, ...]

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig_scale = 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4*fig_scale,3*fig_scale))
gs1 = plt.GridSpec(2, 1,height_ratios=[1, 0.05])
axes = plt.subplot(gs1[0,0], projection=ccrs.Robinson(central_longitude=0.0))


mappab = plt.scatter(x=lon, y=lat,
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

axes.coastlines(color='grey')
axes.gridlines()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does the set_global method help? https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/generated/cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.html?highlight=set_global#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.set_global

Comment: Needs `axes.set_global()` to get the whole world plot.

Comment: And don't use `plt.scatter()` but `axes.scatter()` to avoid confusion. You also have another subplot according to your GridSpec().

Comment: Yes, axes.set_global() does exactly what I want. Thank you!